# Sign convention in trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

[image: for people who are confused about graphical and circular sense]So, as I have read and even been taught by my teachers, sign convention in trigonometric functions is based on the location of the respective x and y points denoting the coordinates of a particle going around a circle.
Although I am kind of sure that I am right but I still want to confirm this one thing:

When determining the slope of a graph, we encounter both obtuse and acute angles (the angle made by the tangent of the graph at a particular point on it with the x axis). So, is it just a coincidence that tan(a)(the angle made by the tangent) is positive in case of acute angles and negative in case of obtuse angles in both this graphical sense as well as tan(a) for a point on a circle?

Because if a is obtuse(graph), that would mean that the quantity in the y axis is decreasing and if it is increasing, the angle is positive. So, I just want to ask that here tan(a) just happens to be equal to the slope of the graph right? I checked for other trigonometric functions and well sin(a) seems to be negative if the angle is obtuse in the graphical sense but positive in the circular sense.

Edit: I have added a picture for clarity about my definition of graphical and circular sense.

Comment: I don't follow.  You are asking why $\sin(120^\circ)$ (*noting that $120^\circ$ is an obtuse angle*) is negative?  It isn't... it's positive.  What do you mean that you think it is negative "*in the graphical sense*"?

Comment: @Chahak,What is graphical sense as per you?What is graphical vs circular sense,Defining your understandings properly will help users here On MSE Reply to your doubts better

Comment: @JMoravitz I have added a picture for more clarity

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi I have added an image for more clarity

Comment: I still have no idea what you are talking about for how you are trying to define things like sine and cosine in a "graphical sense."  All I see is an arbitrary squiggle of a graph and some imprecise words talking about angles and tangents to a graph... What graph specifically?

Comment: @JMoravitz, when I say sin(a) seems to be negative in graphical sense, I mean that (y2-y1)/(length of the tangent) is negative if the angle is obtuse

Comment: "length of the tangent"  "y2-y1" what are these with respect to $a$ and $\sin(a)$?  Nothing yet has been defined.  This all sounds very imprecise and probably incorrect.

Comment: I forgot how to use the symbol for "theta" while typing, so I am using "a", y2-y1 just define the distance from the origin to the y intercept, with y1 being zero(I admit it is my mistake to not define the terms), and sin(a) is well just the ratio of y2-y1 with the length of the tangent(the part of the tangent making x and y intercepts).

Comment: I am not a frequent asker here at MSE, this is well my first question to be honest...so I may seem a bit unprofessional but honestly I am just curious

Comment: Again... *with respect to what curve?*  The circle?  Are you perhaps trying to talk about how $\sin$ can be defined with respect to right triangles and their side lengths and having sine be "length of opposite divided by length of hypotenuse" and are asking about for obtuse angles why the image is "flipped"... but then where do tangents come into play here?  The shortest answer is that this is a bad way to define things and you should ignore this definition for this case... Use the official rigorous definitions and then there should be no confusion

Comment: It actually doesn't matter what curve, I just want to compare the signs of trigonometric functions on the basis of angle made by the tangents to that curve with the x axis and the angle made by the radius of that particle moving around that circular curve

Comment: "*It actually doesn't matter what curve*"... So, if I give a pen to my 4 year old nephew and let him scribble a random doodle and use that as your curve... you expect that curve and tangents to that curve that they should have some inherent connection to $\sin$ and $\cos$?  Ludicrous.  For us to define things like $\sin$ and $\cos$ we should need to talk about a *specific* curve, surely.

Comment: Well that's very very debatable,  if there are angles, there are trigonometric functions with respect to them and we should be able to arrive at the same sign conventions for any given curve because that's how mathematical proofs should work and if you think that I am wrong I am happy to be proven wrong. Please be respectful as people here are just curious not to be look down on.

Comment: For me to "prove you wrong" we must first be using the same definitions.  Since it seems we are not, the best I can do is inform you that you should use precise and proper definitions that are agreed upon by the community.  Upon doing so, then your question becomes moot.

Comment: Draw the Cartesian Plane and write "A" in Quadrant I, "S" in Quadrant II, "T" in Quadrant III, and "C" in Quadrant IV.  (can be remembered as "All Students Take Calculus").  In QI, All trig functions are positive; in QII, Sine is positive (along with its reciprocal Cosecant); in QIII, Tangent is positive (along with its reciprocal Cotangent); in QIV, Cosine is positive (along with its reciprocal Secant).

Answer (score 1):

When a line crosses the $x$ axis, four angles are formed. Two of the angles are acute (and equal magnitude). The other two angles are obtuse (and equal magnitude).

In the unit circle definition of an angle, angles have a direction as well as a magnitude. If you travel counterclockwise around the circle you get a positive angle. If you travel clockwise, the angle is negative.

When we speak of the angle at which a tangent line crosses the axis, we usually mean the acute angle and not the obtuse angle, even though there is always an obtuse angle whenever there is an acute angle.

Moreover, we think of the angle as having a direction like the angles we can make in the unit circle. To make an acute angle above the $x$ axis and below the tangent line, you can rotate a line from the $x$ axis counterclockwise through an acute angle. So the resulting angle value is positive. But to make an acute below the $x$ axis and above the tangent line, you would rotate the line clockwise, so the angle value is negative.

In this way you always get an angle between $-90^\circ$ and $90^\circ$.

Another way to look at this is that we want to compare the direction of the right half of the $x$ axis withe the right half of the tangent line, not the top half of the tangent line. Let the value of $x$ be increasing on both sides of the angle.

If you know the slope of a tangent line and you want to know its angle, the standard method is to find the arc tangent of the slope. Again, this always gives an answer between $-\pi/2$ radians and $\pi/2$ radians, that is, between $-90^\circ$ and $90^\circ$.

If you choose to consider an angle that is different from the angle everyone else is looking at, you may get unusual results.

Another thing you are doing differently is to ask about the sines of angles. The slope of a line at angle $\theta$ is $\tan(\theta)$, not $\sin(\theta)$.
But I think that the choice of how to describe the angle between a line and the $x$ axis is the main concern here, because you’re looking at the tangent line with assumptions that will make it hard to understand how other people talk about it.

It is an excellent thing that you have chosen to ask this question, however, because every apparent contradiction we find in standard mathematics is a sign that we missed how other people defined things (or that we made some mistake), and this kind of confusion can make it very difficult to do mathematics. And I don’t know any solution to that difficulty other than asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think I get Where your confusion lies,Though comment made by @Jmoravitz is accurate to point that we should have same **language** to talk about things,in this case,**Definitions** matter a lot, Now you, due to some reason I don't follow,Try to differentiate between graphical sense and circular sense, The trigonometric functions for "any angle" are defined using unit circle,This does not mean they might not apply to angles in "*graphical sense*" that you seem to perceive,Angles are angles,No matter where they are,either associated to  unit circle,Or between some random curve's tangent and "x-axis"

Now,trigonometric functions such as $\tan\theta$,Here,happens to be slope of Tangent making angle:$\theta$ with *x-axis*,If slope of Tangent would have happened to be Some other function,We would have used That Function instead Of $\tan\theta$

Now one could also argue that It is intuitive why tangent function and Slope of tangent relate for positive slopes ,i.e $0\leq\theta\leq90°$,Because before extension of Trigonometric ratios to trigonometric functions, the definition of slope Of tangent and definition of $\tan\theta$
Co-incides ,or precisely the same,

To be clear the extension of definition of trigonometric ratios to functions was not a co-incidence,Mathematicians already knew that they would have to include negative slope in order to again *co-incides* the tangent function with slope